# Agency wants me to create online account with (intrusive) platform

Tags: negotiation, new-hires, privacy

I do promotional work through agencies that get various contracts. Some agencies have started using an online platform which I have a problem with. In order to register for an account, lots of professional and personal information is required. Brief example of some questions are:

1. how much do you expect to get paid (this will depend on the job)
2. what is your age (this is illegal for an employer to ask)
3. what is your shoe size (this is irrelevant for the positions I'm interested in)

I recently worked for an agency where they wanted me to use that specific platform. I told them I wasn't comfortable with it and they said I could have alternative arrangements. I completed my shift and they asked if I could fill out the platform account but skip irrelevant details. This is because it integrates with their payroll which would be easier to process. The form doesn't let me click "next" unless a reasonable value is entered so I'd have to fill out something believable but fake (I'm not sure if they know this).

My concern is, when I create an account, I'm not sure who is able to view the information. For example can any register agency? If so, I don't want to put false information and have another agency think it's true. Also things like my salary expectations I can't just put any number down. How should I explain this? Any alternatives I haven't considered?

The agency was good to work with and pays well. Also they seem reasonable to negotiate with on this. I would like to keep on good terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they said you could have alternative arrangements and you have that in writing then send them an invoice with sufficient bank details to enable payment (the isbn number is usually sufficient).

Waiting for you to do the work then asking you to use the software anyway is just devious...

Of course you could fill out the expected pay with the largest number that box will accept - but if that is used to select suitable workers you could loose out.

Answer (score 1):

While the question you have are reasonable, only the site in question can explain their privacy policy and only you can decide whether you trust that explanation.

As for the alternatives: You never tried telling your potential employer "No, as mentioned before, I will not create an account with them. How will we proceed from here?".

You could also ask others in the same position (your coworkers) how they do it.